# postgres + dblink + prepared statements always "busy"

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, dblink

I am using prepared statements and dblink together as part of an async queue management solution.

The setup is basically as such:

1. there is a procedure `worker(n)` which `PREPARE`'s the query templates (once) and `EXECUTE`s queries (n times) and then `DEALLOCATE`s
2. there is a daemon procedure `daemon(i)` that keeps `i` x worker's active in parallel by executing `worker(n)` via dblink's `dblink_send_query`

I have done this sort of daemon+worker technique many times but not with prepared statements and my a/b tests show that it is very clearly the prepared statement that is the issue. The issue I am hitting is that the `dblink_is_busy` status never goes to 0 (i.e. finished/not busy) despite the fact that I *know* the async query is done (I have ways of probing to determine this).

So then the question is why `dblink_is_busy = 1` forever? Is it waiting for some sort of signal like a `COMMIT;` (tried that, it throws a obscure error `EXECUTE of transaction commands is not implemented`)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a nuance in my testing that was causing this (possibly lock contention that is somehow not getting reported despite error logging), not the prepared statements. Leaving the post up in case the question ever comes up for someone else. I have validated that this simple test scenario works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp.test() AS
$$
BEGIN

PREPARE test(NUMERIC) AS
    SELECT pg_sleep($1)
;

FOR i IN 1..1000
LOOP
    EXECUTE 'EXECUTE test(0.01)';
END LOOP
;

DEALLOCATE test;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;

SELECT dblink_send_query('test', 'CALL temp.test(); SELECT nextval(''global.test'');');
```

After ~10s `SELECT dblink_is_busy('test');' will go from 1 → 0 which is the result I was looking for.